# What is the best way to save a generic object in Mongo to a Trace System?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am noob on MEAN development and i want to do something like a trace system that save the user who do the action, which action he did and the object he modified.I want to know which type has to be the field object to save the changes of the object modified and use this model to save the changes of all collections.

This is my Trace model:

```
    var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var TraceSchema = new Schema({
    user: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    action: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    object: {
       // which type do i have to put here or how can i do this?
    },
    collection: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    date:{
        type:Date,
        default: Date.now()
    }
});

mongoose.model('Trace', TraceSchema);
```